# Windowsでローカル開発専用SSL証明書を発行する方法

Tags: windows, https, openssl

Windowsでローカル開発専用SSL証明書を発行する基本的なやり方は下記通りですが、ブラウザーは証明書に信用したくないままです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

行った行動を論述します。

### 段階１ OpenSSLで証明書を発行

OpenSSLはWindowsに入ってませんから、Git Bashから実行します。

```bash
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

入力した情報は

```
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:JP
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:Tokyo
Locality Name (eg, city) []:Tokyo
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:Yamato Daiwa
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:Development
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:localhost
Email Address []:tokugawa.takesi@gmail.com
```

### 段階２ centmgrからの操作

「信頼されたルート証明書機関」へインポートします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

下図、次へ進む事しかできません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ファイルパスを指定します。「.pem」形式はWindowsにより期待されないようなので、ファイルを表示させるには、ファイルピッカーで「全てのファイル」を事前に指定しなければいけません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

「信頼されたルート証明機関」へ配置します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

確認モーダルで「OK」をクリックしたら、手順が完了なはずです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上記の手順に漏れた行動は何ですか？

Comment: 「説明書」を提示してください。

Comment: @sayuri 他言語なので、お役に立ちません。書かれた通りやれば上手く行くような日本語の説明書がございましたら、リンクをお願いしたいと思っております。

Comment: 他言語だろうと、その「説明書」に従って操作したなら提示してください。操作が誤っていたのか、説明書がもともと誤っていたのかは重要なポイントです。

Comment: @sayuri このトピックスの内容は「Windowsでローカル開発専用SSL証明書を発行する方法」、説明書には関係ありません。これ以上トピックスのフォーカスがずれない様に、質問から説明書への参照を取り除きました。

Comment: 質問とは全く無関係かもしれませんが、起点となるエラー画面に同じものがあったので何か参考になるかも？ [SSL設定時に表示されるエラーや警告の原因を徹底解明！～ブラウザエラー編～](https://ssl.sakura.ad.jp/column/ssl-browser-error/)

Comment: ChromeはCNが無効だと言っていますが、CNやその他フィールドには何を設定したのでしょうか？Chromeの場合、IPアドレスでのアクセス時は[SAN IPを検証する](https://qiita.com/Yasuwo/items/c6fd5089bfc6bd8ce709)ようです。

Comment: 「段階1」のコマンドを実行した後、`Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:`等のメッセージと共に、何らかの入力を求められたはずです。その時に何を入力したのか、それとも何も入力せずにEnterだけを押し続けたのか、質問に追記してください。すくなくともEnterキーを数回押さない限りコマンドは終了しないため、その詳細がわからないと正確な再現ができず、何が悪かったのかを示すことができません。

Comment: @raccy 段階１で入力した情報を記載しました。入力せずに飛ばした項目はありません。

Comment: @alpha 恐れ入りますが、「ＣＮ」とは何でしょうか？ところで、Firefoxから開いてみても効果が同じでした。

Comment: [リンク先](https://qiita.com/Yasuwo/items/c6fd5089bfc6bd8ce709)に記載されている通り、CN=Common Name、SAN=Subject Alternative Nameのことです。IPアドレスの場合はブラウザー毎に検証方法が異なり、リンク先ではFirefoxは未調査なので仕様は不明です。

Comment: 追記によるとCN=localhostとしたようですが、ブラウザーでアクセスする時もlocalhostでアクセスしていますか？（エラーメッセージではIPアドレスになっていますが）

Comment: @alpha はい。「127.0.0.1」、「localhost」、「localhost:443」、「127.0.0.1:443」、全部試しました。HTTPSの場合、どちらか一つだけになるでしょうか？

Comment: [ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALIDはmissing_subjectAltNameの意味であるとの情報](https://kanasys.com/tech/658)があります。やはりChromeはCNは見なくてSANを見るようですので、SANを指定してみてください。opensslの使い方が分からなかったので回答としては書きませんが、VisualSVN Serverで生成したSAN付きの自己署名証明書ではアクセスできました。

Answer (score 1):

証明書はただ存在すればいいというものではありません。

> ```
> Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:localhost
> ```

と入力して作成された証明書は `https://localhost/` のアドレスの正当性を証明するものとなります。

他方、ブラウザーのエラーメッセージには「**127.0.0.1**では、～」と表示されています。証明書とは異なる `https://127.0.0.1/` でアクセスされたのでしょうか？

ここまでの説明で分かると思いますが、

- 証明書が証明するアドレス
- ブラウザーがアクセスするアドレス

を一致させる必要があります。この場合の一致とは、ネットワーク的な一致ではなく文字列としての一致です。

Comment: ご回答、ありがとうございます。「証明書とは異なる https://127.0.0.1/」ー言葉の意味を理解しても、『証明書とは異なる』の総括的な意味が理解できませんでしたが、練習中「https://127.0.0.1/」にアクセスしてみた事があり、これからの実践にもアクセスする予定です。「一致させる必要があります」ーつまり、サーバが「https://127.0.0.1/」で動いていると、「https://localhost」にアクセスしても証明書が効かないという事ですか？どちらにせよ、「https://127.0.0.1/」、「https://localhost」、「https://localhost:443」、「https://127.0.0.1:443/」、全部同じ結果です。どの様に調査を調べ続ければ宜しいか、教えて下さいませんでしょうか？